# Array outside javascript function does not update when pushed to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parse-platform, scope

I am writing a function that updates an array outside the scope of the function and the array does not update with the new values added

```
  var eventArray = [];

  function findStuff(){
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var eventObject = {};
          eventObject["id"] = results[i].id
          eventObject["name"] = results[i].get("name")
          eventArray.push(eventObject)
          console.log(eventObject)
      }
      eventArray = JSON.stringify({ "data":eventArray})
      console.log(eventArray)
      },
        error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  }

  findStuff();
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ "data":eventArray}))
```

Comment: The `.find()` operation is **asynchronous**.  The "success" function is called when the operation completes, and that will happen some time *after* the `.find()` call itself returns. It starts the operation but does not wait for it to finish, in other words.

Comment: @pointy So how do I fix this? How can I use the array after it finishes updating?

Comment: Do it *inside* the "success" callback - the whole point of that callback is to allow you to schedule work to be done when the operation completes.

Comment: I actually need to get the info out of the callback, is this possible? I have a function I need the values for outside the .find(). I need them returned really but I cannot find a way to do this

Comment: No, it's not possible. Look at the question & answers linked as a duplicate of this one. You have to change the structure of the application: instead of expecting functions like this to return values, you design them to allow callbacks to be passed in.